# How to do not null valildation with if then using RegEx regular expressions

Tags: regex

I'm trying to do not null check on a field name using regex.  If true, then proceed to concatenate a string value to that field.

My code for concatenating a string with my field:  (?<"fieldname">^(.|\n)*$) 
nworks just fine.  Now I need to apply an if then statement over this to only do so when the <"fieldname"> is not null.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

I've tried (?(<"fieldname">\S)(?<"fieldname">^(l|\n)*$)) but it didn't work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try `(?<fieldname>^(.|\n)+$)`

Comment: What language are you using / what flavour of regex? What are these input fields - XML?

Comment: A regex for any character is `.` sort of like `if var.length() > 0`

Answer (score 1):

Change `*` in your regex to `+`, so that it won't allow an empty string. `+` repeats the previous token one or more times where `*` repeats the previous token zero or more times.

```
(?<fieldname>^(.|\n)+$)
```